# C program dumps the core for same input when run multiple times

Tags: c

I am a seismologist, and I am very new to C. I have been trying to write some code trying to learn C and do my job at the same time. This is the code I have written. :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


int main()
{
    char *token,station[100],earthquake[100],*stn[50],*eq[50],*a="abc";
    float lat_st,long_st,lat_eq,long_eq,e=0.0000001;
    int c=1;
//--------------------------------------------------------This code block takes the input and checks whether the input has only two values - one for latitude and one for longitude and processes the input string for further analysis-----------------------------------------------------------------------// 
a:      printf("Input Station Lat-Long: ");
    scanf("%s",station);
    token=strtok(station,", ");
    int i=0;
    while(token!=NULL)
    {
        stn[i]=token;
        token=strtok(NULL,", ");
        i++;
    }

    if (atoi(stn[2])){
        printf("More than two values for latitude and longitude entered. Please enter again.\n\n");
        stn[2]=a;
        goto a;
    }
b:  printf("Input Earthquake Lat-Long: ");
    scanf("%s",earthquake);
    token=strtok(earthquake,", ");
    i=0;
    while(token!=NULL)
    {
        eq[i]=token;
        token=strtok(NULL,", ");
        i++;
    }


    if (atoi(eq[2])){
        printf("More than two values for latitude and longitude entered. Please enter again.\n\n");
        eq[2]=a;
        goto b;
    }

//---------------------------------------------------End of first check. Next check is to find out whether the input is in quadrant (23N,45W) or azimuthal (23,-45) convention and convert quadrant to azimuthal if required-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//


else{
    for(i=0;stn[0][i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(stn[0][i]>57)
        {

            switch (stn[0][i]){
                case 'N':
                c=1;
                break;

                case 'n':
                c=1;
                break;

                case 'S':
                c=-1;
                break;

                case 's':
                c=-1;
                break;

                default:
                printf("Wrong input. Please enter again.\n\n");
                goto a;
            }
            stn[0][i]='\0';

        }
    }
    lat_st=c*atoi(stn[0]);
    c=1;

    for(i=0;stn[1][i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(stn[1][i]>57)
        {

            switch (stn[1][i]){
                case 'E':
                c=1;
                break;

                case 'e':
                c=1;
                break;

                case 'W':
                c=-1;
                break;

                case 'w':
                c=-1;
                break;

                default:
                printf("Wrong input. Please enter again.\n\n");
                goto a;
            }
            stn[1][i]='\0';

        }
    }
    long_st=c*atoi(stn[1]);
    c=1;

    for(i=0;eq[0][i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(eq[0][i]>57)
        {

            switch (eq[0][i]){
                case 'N':
                c=1;
                break;

                case 'n':
                c=1;
                break;

                case 'S':
                c=-1;
                break;

                case 's':
                c=-1;
                break;

                default:
                printf("Wrong input. Please enter again.\n\n");
                goto b;
            }
            eq[0][i]='\0';

        }
    }
    lat_eq=c*atoi(eq[0]);
    c=1;

    for(i=0;eq[1][i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(eq[1][i]>57)
        {

            switch (eq[1][i]){
                case 'E':
                c=1;
                break;

                case 'e':
                c=1;
                break;

                case 'W':
                c=-1;
                break;

                case 'w':
                c=-1;
                break;

                default:
                printf("Wrong input. Please enter again.\n\n");
                goto b;
            }
            eq[1][i]='\0';

        }
    }
    long_eq=c*atoi(eq[1]);
}
//------------------------------------End of second check. Third check is to determine if any lat value is too close to 90 to cause any problems---------------------//

    printf("%f %f %f %f",lat_st,long_st,lat_eq,long_eq);
    return 0;
}
```

All that has been done yet in the code is to figure out ways in which the user can screw things up. But for some reason I sometimes get a segmentation fault for the same input, and sometimes I don't. Sample terminal output:

```
$ ./a
    Input Station Lat-Long: 23N,45E
    Input Earthquake Lat-Long: 34N,56E
    23.000000 45.000000 34.000000 56.000000
$ ./a
    Input Station Lat-Long: 23,45
    Input Earthquake Lat-Long: 34,56
    23.000000 45.000000 34.000000 56.000000
$ ./a
    Input Station Lat-Long: 23S,45
    Input Earthquake Lat-Long: 34,54W
    -23.000000 45.000000 34.000000 -54.000000
$ ./a
    Input Station Lat-Long: 23,45
    Input Earthquake Lat-Long: 45,56
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I can pretty much understand that my code is bad, but I can't see any errors, or am I missing something?

Thank you

edit: @BLUEPIXY 's solution seems to be working, but my question remains as to why would the output be different on different runs of the program?

Comment: `gcc` is the compiler. The core dump comes from your program not `gcc`. To debug such issues use a debugger (`gdb` if using Linux). Learning to use a debugger will be more beneficial to you in the long term than just having someone debug the current issue for you.

Comment: I know you are a beginner so I say this with good intentions - your code structure needs to be rewritten. Having `goto` statements all over the place is a sure sign of poor structure and will only result in fragile and difficult to debug code.

Comment: `if (atoi(stn[2])){` is wrong. E.g input: `11,22`, `stn[0]`:`11`,`stn[1]`:`22`, `stn[2]` is uninitialized. Check `i` instead of.

Comment: @kaylum, thank you for you suggestions. I will get around to learning the debugger one I learn C. But for now I need some Idea about what's wrong. Even if I remove goto, why would the outputs be different for basically the same input? Shouldn't the output remain same for the same input and same code?

Comment: @Archon Learning how to use the debugger is not something you "will get around to learning." It is something you need right away to solve this particular problem on your own.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, I was trying to check if stn[2] has been initialised. eg: input: `stn[0]=11,stn[1]=22,stn[2]=33` then the input is wrong because latitude and longitude can't have more than two values. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: When input as `11,22`, `stn[2]` is not assigned. Can't use for test.E.g `if(i != 2){error handling}` instead of `if (atoi(stn[2])){`

Comment: @DYZ, I will try debugging the code myself using gdb. But my question remains, why would the outputs be different for basically the same input? Shouldn't the output remain same for the same input and same code?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, yes, thanks. I didn't think of that at all.